# php Path not found. Include expression is not resolved

Tags: php, path, phpstorm, subdirectory, include-once

The website Javascript and CSS is not working because included path seems not work, PHPStorm shows that path not found. But the path is correct as image 1:  [image: index.php.png]

I think the problem is APP_DIR, removed it and PHPStorm did not highlight the path anymore.

As image 2: 
[image: no highlight]

But I cannot remove the APP_DIR because it link to many files including CSS. 
Been trying for 3 days and I have no idea, help me please.

Comment: Not sure what the code hint exactly shows: a) APP_DIR is not defined or b) APP_DIR has no trailing slash ?

Comment: IDEs are not really good at resolving dynamic paths. Try running the script, what does it show? Any error?

Comment: i think you should try include_once(APP_DIR.'/conf/site.php')

Comment: My apologies and sorry to everyone who tried to help me, I've given up on this. I'd uploaded the source code(50mb) if anyone want to try it. Thanks. https://goo.gl/kaZeDa

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes please try

```
if ( !defined('APP_DIR') ) {
    trigger_error('APP_DIR not defined', E_USER_ERROR);
}

if ( substr(APP_DIR, -1)!=='/' && substr(APP_DIR, -1)!=='\\' ) {
    trigger_error("APP_DIR has no trailing slash. APP_DIR.'conf/....' wont work, but APP_DIR.'/conf/...' might");
}

/** Configuration of SI */
include_once APP_DIR.'conf/site.php';
```

Comment: Sorry VolkerK, I appreciate your help. I've given up on this. I'd uploaded the source code(50mb) if you want to try it. Thanks. https://goo.gl/kaZeDa